# What does "over the unit square" mean?

Tags: probability-distributions

So i was told that a joint distribution of two volumes $X$ and $Y$ (both ranging from 0 to 1) is $f(x)=c(x+y^2)$ over the unit square, 0 otherwise.

My question might be trivial, but I've never seen this expression before, what does "over the unit square" mean?

Comment: $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: That should be $f(x,y)=c(x+y^2)$, a function of two variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the joint distribution is nonzero only at points in the square with all side-lengths 1 lying in the first quadrant with one corner at the origin and sides lying along the positive $x$- and $y$-axes.

In other words, it consists of the points with $x$ and $y$ coordinates both between $0$ and $1$.

(Note: "unit" refers to the number $1$.  A unit square has side-length 1, and *the* unit square is the unique such square contained in the first quadrant with one corner at the origin.)

Answer (score 2):

"Unit" means one. "Unit square" is a square with length 1 on each side (restating what you already said: $X$ and $Y$ range from 0 to 1). "Unit circle" is a circle with radius 1. And so forth.

**Edit:** The words "over" or "on" can be used to refer to the domain of a particular function. This presents an interesting case, because while many of us are familiar with this usage, going through a half-dozen books on my shelf, I can't find any that formally declare/define that usage. As one example, in the [Wikipedia article on functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29), the word "over" gets used in the middle of an example without prior usage:

> The unique function over a set $X$ that maps each element to
>   itself is called the *identity function* for $X$.

Likewise for the [article on domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) which starts using the word "on" in the middle of an example:

> For example, the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=1/x$ has no value for
>   $f(0)$.  Thus, the set of all real numbers, $\mathbb R$, cannot be its
>   domain. In cases like this, the function is either defined on $\mathbb R$\{0} or the "gap is plugged" by explicitly defining $f(0)$.

Another term that might have been used for the question here is [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29), which is the part of the domain that produces nonzero values for the function.

Comment: And what does "over" mean? :)

Comment: Actually, unit does not mean "one". Unit refers to a standardized size and hence also refers to "one unit" - but not to "one". @avid "$A$ over $B$" means "$B$ under $A$". For *under*, see *over*.

Comment: @avid19: That's part of "a function f(x,y) over D" - D is (part of the) _domain_ of  {x,y}, that its to say possible values which x,y} can take.

Comment: I think "over" was the more relevant part of the question.

Comment: Edited to discuss the "over" usage.